# Multiple tables from mysql to one table in python

Tags: python, mysql-python

In Python, with the use of MYSQL how do you make table from multiple tables. I have found a solution for 2 tables but I do not know how to do it for more that 2 tables. This is the schema:

```
emp (eno CHAR(5), ename VARCHAR(30), bdate DATE, title CHAR(2), salary DECIMAL(9,2), supereno CHAR(5), dno CHAR(5), PRIMARY KEY (eno))
dept (dno CHAR(5), dname VARCHAR(40), mgreno CHAR(5), PRIMARY KEY (dno))                      
proj (pno CHAR(5), pname VARCHAR(40), budget DECIMAL(9,2), dno  CHAR(5), PRIMARY KEY (pno)) 
workson (eno  CHAR(5), pno  CHAR(5), resp VARCHAR(20), hours SMALLINT, PRIMARY KEY (eno,pno))
```

And This is what I have tried so far:

```
import mysql.connector
connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='', password='', host='', database='')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = ("SELECT ename, w.eno, sum(hours), p.pno, pname, budget, d.dno, dname, mgreno FROM emp e, workson w, proj p, dept d WHERE e.eno=w.eno AND w.pno=p.pno AND p.dno=d.dno "+" budget > %s")
cursor.execute(query, (140000))
for (ename, eno, sum(hours), pno, pname, budget, dno, dname, mgreno) in cursor:
        print(pno, pname, dno, dname, sum(hours), mgreno)
cursor.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have two wheres, i.e. `WHERE Where`.
2. Use `AND` to separate the different clauses of the condition, not `,`. So the end of your SQL should be:

```
WHERE e.eno = w.eno AND w.pno = p.pno AND p.dno = d.dno AND budget > %s
```

3. `sum(hours)` is a function call, not a valid variable name, so it can't be the target in a for loop, i.e. `for (ename, eno, sum(hours), ...`. Just make up a variable name, like `sum_hours`.
4. `(140000)` is just `140000`, not a tuple. If you want a tuple with one element, you need a comma, i.e. `(140000,)`. You can also just use a list: `[140000]`.

Comment: Im getting a syntax error saying: cant assign to function call even after the fix,